# PHP: echo return parameters from powershell script

Tags: php, powershell

I want to execute powershell script through PHP, And want return parameters in PHP variable. So for testing, I have tried to get windows version from powershell script.

```
<?php 

exec("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  gwmi     win32_operatingsystem | % caption",$output );

echo( '<pre>' );
var_dump( $output );
echo( '</pre>' );

?>
```

output:

```
C:\wamp64\www\py\indexPHP.php:6:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

but it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Your call is incorrect.

```
exec("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command (GWMI Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption", $Output);
```

Comment: @SDA I don't know PHP, but looking at the documentation, it would appear you need to make a reference to the array you're spewing into.  So for example, declare `$Output` before `exec()` and then use `&$Output`

Comment: its doesnt work as well, i think there might be security issues, running exec  command... because simple codes are not working  and no error logged

Comment: thanks for helping... but still it doesnt works... can you please check this code in your pc ?.. so problem can get narrow may be there is some problem with my wamp